# should-be-working jQuery .post() function to HTML via PHP?

Tags: jquery, jquery-post

I went through the code at the following two links:
http://pastebin.com/iUd22CRY
http://www.jensbits.com/2009/10/04/jquery-ajax-and-jquery-post-form-submit-examples-with-php

Everything seems pretty clear in the code itself, but I can't figure out the complete story of which codeblocks are associated with which filenames.  Basically, I am trying to find an up-to-date guide to using jQuery's post function for interactions with a PDO object, and I have been very unsuccessful in doing so.

What I plan to do next is attempt to convert/update an example from w3schools, if I cannot figure out what the filenames should be.  Basically, with the pastebin, I think I know where the first three paragraphs of code go, but I have no idea where to place the javascript near the end.  Before I slum, though, I was hoping someone would look over my code.  Can you see the problem?

-Edit-
I have noticed an error via Chrome's console (`ctrl+shift+j` in-browser): `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ; encode.js:17` http://ajform.99k.org/issues/semicolon/ or `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined encode.js:1` http://ajform.99k.org/issues/orderofappearance/

Filesystem structure:

`webroot/sitename/index.php`; `webroot/sitename/process_form.php`; `webroot/sitename/js/jquery-1.8.2.js`; `webroot/sitename/js/encode.js`

index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Tmp homepage</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/encode.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<form id="ajform">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>jQuery.post Form Submit example</legend>
        <p>
            <label for="name">Name:</label></br />
            <input id="name" type="text" name="name" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="email">email:</label></br />
            <input id="email" type="text" name="email" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
</form>
<div id="post"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

encode.js:

```
$(document).ready(
  $(function(){
      $("#ajform").submit(function(e){    
         e.preventDefault();  

          $.post("../process_form.php", $("#ajform").serialize(),
          function(data){
              if(data.email_check == 'invalid'){

                      $("#post").html("<div class='errorMessage'>Sorry " + data.name + ", " + data.email + " is NOT a valid e-mail address. Try again.</div>");
              } else {
                  $("#post").html("<div class='successMessage'>" + data.email + " is a valid e-mail address. Thank you, " + data.name + ".</div>");
                  }
          }, "json");    
      });

  });
)
```

process_form.php:

```
<?php

$email_check = '';
$return_arr = array();

if(filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) || filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
   $email_check = 'valid';
}
else {
    $email_check = 'invalid';
}


$return_arr["email_check"] = $email_check;

if (isset($_POST['email'])){
    $return_arr["name"] = $_POST['name'];
    $return_arr["email"] = $_POST['email'];
}

echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

-Edit-
After working through the errors, thanks to answerers, the working version is at [hhttp://www.jensbits.com/demos/jqsubmit/index.php](http://www.jensbits.com/demos/jqsubmit/index.php).

Comment: I'm not finding `js/encode.js` on your site.

Comment: You script tag is wrong.  The src attribute should be `/js/encode.js` instead of `encode.js`.

Comment: @slashingweapon Thank you.  It has been fixed.  This is a link: http://ajform.99k.org/js/encode.js

Comment: There is a syntax error in encode.js.  Check your browser's console for details.

Comment: @slashingweapon I've caught those, also.  Trying to find a similar issue on google.  It seems I need to list the jQuery script before the encode script.

Comment: @slashingweapon <3 http://ajform.99k.org/?name=df&email=df

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19064/discussion-between-slashingweapon-and-wolfpack08)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `<script type="text/javascript" src="encode.js"></script>` isn't loading. It's returning a 404.

And, put `encode.js` AFTER the jquery js.

View the source on the demo from my post that you cited. It will help you out.

http://www.jensbits.com/demos/jqsubmit/index.php

Thanks, BTW...

Comment: I just saved a bad draft, by mistake, due to a copy/paste error.  The change has now been committed on the server.  The new link is `js/encode.js`.  Thank you.

Comment: @Wolfpack'08 answer updated. Put your scripts in the right order.

Comment: Yeah, that's the tutorial I went through.  It's dope.  I saw the demo, but it didn't work on my system due to the mistake I made, which you mention in your answer (order of appearance of .js scripts).  If you go to the ajform site I posted, you can see I've repaired the error.  I'll put an error-having form up in the question, shortly.

Answer (score 0):

Working code with filenames:

index.php, located at `sitename/index.php`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Tmp homepage</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/encode.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<form id="ajform">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>jQuery.post Form Submit example</legend>
        <p>
            <label for="name">Name:</label></br />
            <input id="name" type="text" name="name" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="email">email:</label></br />
            <input id="email" type="text" name="email" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
</form>
<div id="post"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

process_form.php, located at `sitename/process_form.php` (php 5.2 or later [may vary based on your config]):

```
<?php

$email_check = '';
$return_arr = array();

if(filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) || filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
   $email_check = 'valid';
}
else {
    $email_check = 'invalid';
}


$return_arr["email_check"] = $email_check;

if (isset($_POST['email'])){
    $return_arr["name"] = $_POST['name'];
    $return_arr["email"] = $_POST['email'];
}

echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

encode.js, located at `sitename/js/encode.js` (using jQuery 1.8.2.min.js):

```
$(document).ready(
  $(function(){
      $("#ajform").submit(function(e){    
         e.preventDefault();  

          $.post("../process_form.php", $("#ajform").serialize(),
          function(data){
              if(data.email_check == 'invalid'){

                      $("#post").html("<div class='errorMessage'>Sorry " + data.name + ", " + data.email + " is NOT a valid e-mail address. Try again.</div>");
              } else {
                  $("#post").html("<div class='successMessage'>" + data.email + " is a valid e-mail address. Thank you, " + data.name + ".</div>");
                  }
          }, "json");    
      });

  })
)
```